# How can I place CheckBox's in a StackPanel dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created an XAML dialog window.  For the most part, I need to populate this window dynamically, which is something I've never tried to tackle before, and I can't find anything on either this site or MSDN.  Here's what I can show from the `.xaml`:

```
<GroupBox Header="Pipe Segments" Height="Auto" Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegRow1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR1C1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR1C2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR1C3" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR1C4" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR1C5" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR1C6" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegRow2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR2C1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR2C2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR2C3" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR2C4" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR2C5" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR2C6" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegRow3" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR3C1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR3C2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR3C3" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR3C4" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR3C5" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR3C6" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegRow4" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR4C1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR4C2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR4C3" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR4C4" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR4C5" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR4C6" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegRow5" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR5C1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR5C2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR5C3" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR5C4" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR5C5" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
             <StackPanel x:Name="PipeSegR5C6" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="90"></StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
     </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

There's a couple more of those in the window.  What I am trying to accomplish is this:  Place new `Checkbox`'s in the `StackPanel` rows and columns dynamically from the contents of a `List<T>`.  Here's what I'm trying, but I'm not sure if it will work, or if I'm even coming at this the right way.  I'd like to point out in advance the the `List<T>` being using initially below is not the one for the `GroupBox` above.  Sorry for the confusion - just know that they're essentially the same thing.

```
public void PopulateWindow()
{
    int itr = 1;                    //TO SCROLL THROUGH THE ROWS AND COLUMNS
    var fecPipes = new FilteredElementCollectoR(m_pDoc);                                                //GET ALL PIPES
    var lstRVTPipes = fecPipes.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).
                          OfClass(typeof(PipeType));    //FILTER RVT PIPES
    var lstMEPSizes = fecPipes.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).
                          OfClass(typeof(MEPSize));     //FILTER NOMINAL DIAMETERS
    var lstPipeSeg = fecPipes.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_PipeCurves).
                          OfClass(typeof(PipeSegment));  //FILTER PIPE SEGMENTS

    foreach (PipeType pPipe in lstRVTPipes)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();                //CREATE NEW CHECK BOX
        cb.Height = 15;                              //SET CHECK BOX HEIGHT
        cb.Name = pPipe.FamilyName.ToString();       //SET THE NAME OF THE CHECK BOX
        cb.Content = pPipe.FamilyName.ToString();    //SET THE CONTENT DISPLAY OF THE CHECK BOX
        switch (itr)                                 //PLACE THE CHECK BOX
        {
            case 1:
                cb.BindingGroup = RVTPipeR1C1.BindingGroup;    //DOES THIS WORK?
                RVTPipeR1C1.DataContext = cb;                  //DOES THIS WORK?

                /* I'D LIKE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE:
                *  RVTPipeR1C1.Add(cb);   OR
                *  cb.Location = RVTPipeR1C1.Location;
                *  BUT THAT'S NOT A OPTION...  :-( */
            break;

            //  THEN IT KEEPS GOING LIKE THIS FOR A WHILE...
            //
            //
        }
    itr++;

    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me how to place these items, or if I'm doing anything right/wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it! Any links to anything that helps is great too!  Thanks!

Comment: Use bindings - WPF already has a means to do stuff like this by using `ItemsControl` and bindings. You shouldn't really need to ever add a control to your pages in codebehind unless it's a special case. Binding to a `List<T>` will work, but it's better if it's a collection that supports collection change notification like `ObservableCollection<T>`, otherwise your UI won't update when the items change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a UIElement to a StackPanel by adding it to the StackPanel's Children property:

```
PipeSegR1C1.Children.Add(cb);
```

A StackPanel has no concept of rows and columns though. It simply arranges child elements into a single line that is oriented horizontally or vertically depending on the value of the Orientation property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to organize your controls in a flexible grid area that consists of columns and rows you could use a Grid element and add ColumnDefinition and RowDefinitions to it. Please refer to MSDN for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties

Comment: I know it doesn't know what rows and columns are; I just placed them as if they were via `Margin`s and `Width`s.  Either way, thanks for the help!!  You're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically placing collection of elements you can use `ItemsControl`. For it you can read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx, https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_2.php and easy example of using it is here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/.

In code you create `ObservableCollection<T>` for your elements, where `T` is `ViewModel` for your `CheckBox`'es.

For your `ItemsControl` you must set `StackPanel` as `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`, `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}"`(where `Elements` is your `ObservableCollection<T>`) and in `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` add `DataTemplate` for your `CheckBox`'es.

I hope, my tips will help you)